# Sudden problems in excel with GoogleTranslate "result_box"

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, google-translate

Last year I had no problem with this code for translation trough Google. But now it gives me a `424` error.

> Object required.

I posted my whole code. But the string where it fails is:

```
arr_Response = Split(.Document.getElementById("result_box").innerHTML,
"<span class")
```

VBA:

```
Public Sub TranslateDescribtion()    
With Ark3.Range("B2", "B105")
' Find translation language
Worksheets("TranslationLanguageLookUp").Activate
TranslateLanguageAdress = .Find(What:=TranslateLanguagesVariable, LookAt:=xlWhole).Address
TranslateLanguageSyntax = Range(TranslateLanguageAdress).Offset(0, 1).Text
Worksheets("Equipments").Activate
End With

'Original Language to translate from
Const INPUT_LANG As String = "en"

'Progress text shown i processbar

Dim ws_ActiveWS As Worksheet
Dim r_ActiveCell As Range, r_InputRange As Range
Dim s_InputStr As String, s_InputLang As String, s_OutputLang As String, arr_Response() As String, s_Translation As String
Dim o_IE As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim v As Variant

Set o_IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

'Declare the inputstring with text to be translated
s_InputStr = DescribtionTVariable

'Output-language
s_OutputLang = TranslateLanguageSyntax

'Navigate to translate.google.com
With o_IE

    .Visible = False 'Run IE in background
    .Navigate "http://translate.google.com/#" & INPUT_LANG & "/" _
        & s_OutputLang & "/" & s_InputStr


    'Split the responseText from Google
    arr_Response = Split(.Document.getElementById("result_box").innerHTML, "<span class")

    'Remove html from response, and construct full-translation-string
    For Each v In arr_Response
        s_Translation = s_Translation & Replace(v, "<span>", "")
        s_Translation = Replace(s_Translation, "</span>", "")
        s_Translation = Replace(s_Translation, """", "")
        s_Translation = Replace(s_Translation, "=hps>", "")
        s_Translation = Replace(s_Translation, "=atn>", "")
        s_Translation = Replace(s_Translation, "=hps atn>", "")

    Next v

    If (s_Translation <> vbNullString) Then
        DescribtionsTranslatedValue = s_Translation

     'Cleanup
    o_IE.Quit

    'Set o_MSForms_DataObject = Nothing
    Set ws_ActiveWS = Nothing
    Set r_ActiveCell = Nothing
    Set o_IE = Nothing

End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd suggest you check the website elements, to see if something has changed in the name of the elements.

Comment: Can you provide an example full url with the variable values and expected result. I also suspect you don't need to do all that removal of html if you use the right selection method.

Comment: Hi Luuklag,, I tried and found I might need to change result_box to "tlid-translation translation", but it will still not work..

Comment: QHarr, for now I just try to translate simple text as "Hello my name is" .. Making the commad o_IE visible i see that my text i copied to the wep page and translated. But i cant bring it back to excel.

Comment: Please provide the full url as it appears in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not convinced I have the same url so providing a full one will help. With reference to the class you mention you can use

```
Debug.Print ie.document.querySelector(".tlid-translation.translation").innerText
```

Comment: This is the URL which opens: https://translate.google.com/#en/is/Hello my name is.

Comment: The code returns the translation, but I can figure out how to get it copied in to the sheet..

Comment: Remove the debug.print and assign to a cell e.g. activesheet.cells(1,1) = ie.document..............

Comment: Thank you so much... I got it to work thanks to you.. Removed all the steps to remove HTML and used your code..

Comment: One small issue is: when translating text which is seperated with enter,,, the tanslation removes theses spaces.

Comment: Can you provide an example url please where this happens.

Comment: https://translate.google.com/#en/da/Hello this is a test.Before this line i type enter 3 times.

Comment: i guess the problem is that moving my text to google, it dosent bring the spaces with it.. So my problem is when sending my text to google and not the other way.

Comment: So, is the problem the sending part or the translation part? If translation part can you give me an example where you expect a multiline response with spaces?

Comment: it seem the comments here on this site also removes the entr spaces